# New file in ubuntu kernel ppa repository to install?

Tags: kernel, updates

Googling this question hasn't brought me to anything so I decided to ask here. Recently I noticed on kernel.org that kernel 3.7 finally considered to be a stable so I decided to upgrade, since I am on 3.7 RC7 but when I opened http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.7.1-raring/

I noticed new file (actually 2 which seems to be identical) 
   `linux-headers-3.7.1-030701-omap_3.7.1-030701.201212171620_armhf.deb`
and

```
linux-image-3.7.1-030701-omap_3.7.1-030701.201212171620_armhf.deb
```

so my question is should I install those as well or continue installing only 4 files (e.g. 3 AMD64 image and headers + all headers)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, those files are for ARM processors not x86 or x86-64 processors. You can see that from the `armhf` at the end and the `omap` following the kernel version.

Comment: ok, that explains the tag.